# Error when saving product: "Duplicate website group price customer group."

Tags: magento-1.8, product, admin, group-price

I get this error message when I try to save a product, which reads to me like a random sequence of nouns (the German translation is even weirder but I am used to that...)

Traced it down to this method in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Groupprice`:

```
/**
 * Error message when duplicates
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getDuplicateErrorMessage()
{
    return Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Duplicate website group price customer group.');
}
```

<del>The weird thing is, the article does not contain any group price. And even if i don't change anything, the message appears. What could possibly be broken here?</del>

Update: Actually there is a group price definition, I did not notice it because it had been moved to the "general" tab:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it... removing the website specific definition solved it. Apparently you cannot combine a customer group price for "All Websites" with customer group prices for specific websites.

Comment: Saved toooooooooooons of hours :) tyvm